# Image downloading on laptop but not on smartphone

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to download an image from different websites to user harddrive in laravel and it  works perfectly on laptop browser(chrome, firefox) but when I try to download it on a smartphone browser(chrome) it shows 404 error ... I really tried hard to solve this issue but nothing happens .... here is my controller

---

**Downloader.php**(controller)

```
 public function file($url){
        $url = base64_decode($url);
        $filename = 'profile_pic_instaleet.jpg';
        $tempImage = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $filename);
        copy($url, $tempImage);
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache',
            'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename,

         ];
        return response()->download($tempImage, $filename, $headers);
    }
```

---

**web.php**(route)

```
Route::get('/download/{url}', 'Downloader@file');
```

**Html Code**

```
<a href="/download/{{ base64_encode($info['hddp']) }}" class="button is-success is-rounded is-fullwidth"><img src="{{ asset('svg/downloads.svg') }}" width="20px"/>&nbsp Download This Profile In HD</a>
```

---

**image link**

```
https://instagram.fixc2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/cd2a2fcbdcbd5b2066c88353d7b8811d/5E539700/t51.2885-19/s320x320/73238666_416113319087062_6640995458049114112_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fixc2-1.fna.fbcdn.net
```

Comment: firstly i tried to download image file without header and after searching a lot on stackoverflow i added header but still getting the same issue @04FS

Comment: So what gives a 404 then exactly? Your attempt to navigate to `/download/…` itself? Have you checked what the server logs have to say about this then?

Comment: Yes it gives 404 to attempt to navigate to that url without downloading image.... But it works perfectly on laptop browser

Comment: go to nalinnishant.com and enter https://www.instagram.com/its._nalin_/?igshid=fm3ai61ip0yp in search box and then try to download pic... And you will know exactly what happening

Comment: Go make that same request from desktop and from mobile once each time then, and go check what your server logs have to say. Start with the access log, and check if the URL looks the same in both cases - or if something got messed up somehow.

Comment: i checked no error showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base64_encode uses some chars that are not url-friendly. The case you mentioned contains a slash:

```
aHR0cHM6Ly9zY29udGVudC1sYXgzLTEuY2RuaW5zdGFncmFtLmNvbS92cC8wNmI0NjcwZGIzZTVjOTU5ODRhZTNlNTA5MmQ2MWQ5Ni81RTRFOTJGNS90NTEuMjg4NS0xOS9zMzIweDMyMC83MjQ4MzMyN18yNTQwNzY3NTQyODc0ODY0XzU3MTE4NzE2NjQwMTEwODM3NzZfbi5qcGc **/** X25jX2h0PXNjb250ZW50LWxheDMtMS5jZG5pbnN0YWdyYW0uY29t
```

This makes your url `http://nalinnishant.com/download/{something}/{something else}` and will not follow Laravel's route of `download/{hash}`. Use a url-safe method of encoding instead of base64.